# How do i execute JavaScript code in Python Selenium and then call it back in my Python code?

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

Here i have some Python code that opens my JavaScript file and executes it into the webpage. I saw posts saying `execute_async_script()` allows for handling of callbacks in JavaScript but i didn't really understand it.

```
with open("script.js") as f:
    script_source = f.read()

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "textArea-2Spzkt")))

script_exc = driver.execute_async_script(script_source)
print("test", script_exc)
```

Here is the JavaScript that Selenium is injecting. It listens for a change in a specific class and outputs a string to the console when it detects a change.

```
// Select the node that will be observed for mutations
var targetNode = document.getElementsByClassName('messagesWrapper-3lZDfY')[0];

// Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
var config = { attributes: false, childList: true, subtree: true };

// Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
var callback = function(mutationsList, observer) {
    for(var mutation of mutationsList) {
        if (mutation.type == 'childList') {
            console.log('A child node has been added or removed.');
        }
        else if (mutation.type == 'attributes') {
            console.log('The ' + mutation.attributeName + ' attribute was modified.');
        }
    }
};

// Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
var observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

// Start observing the target node for configured mutations
observer.observe(targetNode, config);
```

I want to be able to get JavaScript to return a string in the Python console saying `"node change detected"` when a node change is detected. So in my Python code where it say `print("test", script_exc)`, i want it to print `test` and `node change detected`. I'm pretty new to JavaScript as a whole and kinda beginner to Python too. I saw people saying to use `arguments[0]` with JavaScript but i didn't know how that would relate in my Python code.

Answer (score 0):

Use **arguments[0]** with JavaScript means the callback is done.

```
script="var a = 1;"
// if return a, use execute_script()
a = driver.execute_script("return a;")
// or use execute_async_script()
async_script="return arguments[0](a)"
a = driver.execute_async_script(async_script)
```